# why metadata variable is exported in Layout.js file in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, frontend

I'm new to next.js
**I don't understand why metadata variable is exported  from Layout file** and not importing it anywhere

```
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "NextJS App",
  description: "Your first NextJS app!",
};

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I'm learning through the course and documentation and Google.
Not found any idea behind this !!
Guys please do comment !!

**Thanks**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js uses the `metadata` object or `generateMetadata()` function to define the metadata for the corresponding page or layout.

You don't need to import this anywhere. Next.js will automatically read this and insert the relevant tags in the page's `<head>` section.

You typically use metadata for pages to help search engines index your page appropriately. You also use it to display previews in social media platforms like Facebook or X.

[Here's more information on what you can define as metadata for your page.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadata-fields)

---

In your example, since you're using the root layout, any page in your application will have the following tags:

```html
<title>NextJS Ap</title>
<meta name="description" content="Your first NextJS app!" />
```